# How to use Grouping concept in JQWidgets Chart

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, jqwidget

Currently I am using JQWidget Chart in that Grouping the column is not working,can any one suggest how to bring the grouping in JQWidget chart.

Below is the sample table
Number  column1   value   count
1        col1       10     66
2        col1       47     15
3        col1       12     35
1        col2       68     42
2        col2       87     80
3        col2       99     58

Here i need to group the column1 based on Number in categoryAxis(x-axis) and count should binded in series dataField(y-axis) and i need the legend as col1 and col2.

[image]

Comment: can you add some code that you tried or jsfiddles demo

Answer (score 0):

What kind of grouping you were talking about? I don't see if JQWidgets capable to group columns in chart.

See 
http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxchart/index.htm